# How can I put a SearchView on top of a ListView?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and am trying to stack a searchView on top of a ListView. I would Look something like this:

[image]

I don't know how to achieve this layout on flutter, i tried using a column(which crashes the app), used the a stack (which overlaps the widgets) and i finally tried to add a search widget a the first item of the ListView but that didn't result am looking for.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  drawer: _makeDrawer(),
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Center(
      child: new Text("translate"),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.people_outline), onPressed: () {})
    ],
  ),
  body: _phraseListFutureBuilder(), // this part of the code renders the listview
);

}   

   FutureBuilder _phraseListFutureBuilder() {
     return new FutureBuilder(
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
           return mPhrases.isEmpty
               ? new CircularProgressIndicator()
               : _buildPhrases();
         },
         future: _fetchData());
  }
```

Comment: Next time, I would recommend you to include the error message of the crash

Comment: Alright will do, thanks

Comment: howdy @S.Macaneta !  I formatted your code for you - so, I just added spaces in front of the part that did not appear as code.   (When you're editing, there's also a "code"  button at the top -- (1) paste in your slab of code (2) highlight all of it  (3) click the Code button.   Alternately, just add four spaces by hand in front of each line!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Column` was the right choice, but you will also need an `Expanded` widget to specify which widget should fill the remaining space:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Search'
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child:  _phraseListFutureBuilder(),
    )  
  ],
);
```